# Excel change axes places

Tags: excel, axes

Fro example I have in `X` axis `names` in `Y` axe `age` , how to change axis place that in `X` axis will be `age` and in `Y` axis `names`. Solution with change data place is not good, because If I names is 1 row and age 2 I can't change places axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. select column with Y values
2. create diagramm
3. in diagramm options choose "add data" and select column for x values